# Download dynamically generated content in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, csv, dynamic, download

I am trying to download a dynamically generated CSV file over HTTP in VB.net. I have tried various download methods, but all generate the following error:

```
System.Net.WebException was unhandled. The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.
```

The specific CSV file I am trying to fetch is http://www.ukrepeater.net/csvcreate.php

I can only assume the error is due to the fact that the data isn't located at the actual URL referenced, but is just a dynamically generated file that, in a regular browser, just pops-up a download window.

I truly have tried to find every similar question already asked, but I cannot find a solution anywhere. Any code suggestions or links to the answer would be gratefully received!

Comment: try `My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(theURL, myCSVName)`

Comment: Still the same I'm afraid:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `System.Net.WebClient` class. You can save the content of your csv file in a `string` variable:

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
Dim result As String = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.ukrepeater.net/csvcreate.php")
```

or you can download the file to your file system:

```
Dim webClient As New System.Net.WebClient
webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.ukrepeater.net/csvcreate.php", "c:\file.csv")
```

More info about `System.Net.WebClient` can be found on this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page